# dynamically monitor stored procedures executions and cpu - error on dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, dynamic

I am developing a script to monitor stored procedures executions and cpu utilisation, however, running the script below dynamically it does not work. It is working directly in SQL Server Mgmt Studio. Can someone spot something that should be changed?

The error message is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 43
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'proc'.

This is the script:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
--SELECT @SQL ='SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+ QUOTENAME('servername')    + ','''+ '
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT dbID
                      ,dbname
                      ,StoredProcedure
                      ,last_execution_time
                      ,total_cpu_time
                      ,executionCounts
                      ,Total_Logical_Reads
                      ,Total_Logical_Writes 
               FROM OPENQUERY('+ QUOTENAME('servername') + ','''+ '

SET FMTONLY OFF   
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

;with r0 as 
(
   SELECT 
      st.dbID
      ,StoredProcedure = OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,st.dbid)
      ,last_execution_time = MAX(QS.last_execution_time)
      ,total_cpu_time = sum(qs.total_worker_time) 
      ,executionCounts = sum(cp.usecounts)
      ,Total_Logical_Reads=sum(qs.Total_Logical_Reads)
      ,Total_Logical_Writes=sum(qs.Total_Logical_Writes)
   FROM 
      sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
   INNER JOIN 
      sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp ON cp.plan_handle = qs.plan_handle
   CROSS APPLY 
      sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
   WHERE
      cp.objtype = ''proc''--> most of our problems are related to stored procedures 
      --  removing this filter would increase the cost of the query in the monitored servers
      AND OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY
     st.dbid, st.objectid
)
SELECT 
    r0.dbID
    ,DBName = CASE WHEN r0.dbid = 32767 
                     THEN ''Resource''
                     ELSE COALESCE(DB_NAME(r0.dbid), ''No3 Name'') -- keep the coalesce for the database name to be used in a primary key constraint
              END 
    ,r0.StoredProcedure
    ,r0.last_execution_time
    ,r0.total_cpu_time
    ,r0.executionCounts
,r0.Total_Logical_Reads
,r0.Total_Logical_Writes
FROM  
    r0
ORDER BY 
    total_cpu_time DESC' + ''')'

--print @sql
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: 'servername' is a linked server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the joys of dynamic SQL.

You're nesting a string in another string...

Add another set of ' ' around the string literal 'proc' on line 43:

So:
`cp.objtype = ''proc''`

Becomes:
`cp.objtype = ''''proc''''`

A good test is comment out your `EXEC` and uncomment the `PRINT` line.  Then run it to print the string to your window in SSMS.  Then copy the output to a new window...

Notice 'proc' and 'resource and 'No3 Name' are all escaped.  You'll have to add extra ' to all of those literals to make it work.